# General Solution of the Differential Equation $y''+2y'=(1+t)\cos(2t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation
$$y''+2y'=(1+t)\cos(2t)$$
I found the homogenous solution
$$y_H= c_1 e^{-2 x} + c_2$$
For the particular solution I tried
$$y_p=(At+B)\cos(2t)+(Ct+d)\sin(2t)$$
and after finding the derivative and substituting them back in I ended up with
$$-4At-4B+2A+4C+4Ct+4D=1+t$$ $$-4At-4B-4Ct-4D-2C=0$$
I'm not sure these are correct and if they are correct, I'm not sure how to solve them

Comment: Your $y_p$ is good and you have $$y'' + 2 y' = 2 \cos (2 t) (-2 a t+a+2 (-b+c t+c+d))-2 \sin (2 t) (2 a (t+1)+2 b+2 c t-c+2 d) = (t + 1) \cos (2t)$$  Equate like terms and solve for the constants.

Comment: Solving for the constants is where I'm stuck right now

Comment: You get a set of 4 equations in 4 unknowns.

Comment: Note that your constants need to be good for all t. So, you can split this into 4 equations by factoring t's and recognizing the coefficient on t must make both sides equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $y_p$ in the DEQ, we get

$y'' + 2 y' = 2 \cos (2 t) (-2 a t+a+2 (-b+c t+c+d))-2 \sin (2 t) (2 a (t+1)+2 b+2 c t-c+2 d) = (t + 1) \cos (2t)$

When we equate like terms, we have

$$2a - 4b +4c + 4 d = 1 \\ -4 a + 4 c = 1 \\-4a -4 b + 2 c - 4 d = 0 \\-4 a - 4 c = 0$$

I'll assume you can solve that.

**Update** To setup the 4 equations, we have

$$2 \cos (2 t) (-2 a t+a+2 (-b+c t+c+d)) = \cos(2t) + t \cos(2t)$$

Equating the LHS and RHS, we have

$$(2 a - 4 b + 4 c + 4 d) \cos(2 t) = \cos(2t)\\ (-4 a + 4 c) t \cos(2t) = t \cos(2t)$$

Do the same for the $\sin(2t)$ and $t \sin(2t)$ terms.

Comment: So $a=\frac{-1}{8}, b=\frac{-1}{8}, c=\frac{1}{8}, d=\frac{1}{16}$ so my general solution will be $y= c_1 e^{-2 x} + c_2 - \frac{1}{8}t\cos(2t) - \frac{1}{8}\cos(2t)+ \frac{1}{8}t\sin(2t)+ \frac{1}{16}\sin(2t)$

Comment: $$a= -\dfrac{1}{8},b= 0,c= \dfrac{1}{8},d= \dfrac{3}{16}$$ Also, your first term should be a $t$, not $x$.

Comment: Could you just explain how equating the like terms gives four equations?

Comment: See the update.